# Update Java version in Windows 10 WSL

Tags: java, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had openjdk 11.0.2 installed. I upgraded the java version by running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

If I run `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk` again, it shows a message saying that "openjdk-11-jdk is already the newest version (11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04)"

However, when I do java -version it displays the older version 11.0.2 not 11.0.11

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

The JAVA_HOME still shows "/opt/java/jdk-11.0.2", so I guess this might be the problem that the java -version is still showing the older version?

When I do whereis java it shows

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /opt/java/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java /mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath_target_917640/java.exe /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Not sure where the newest version was installed so that I can make the JAVA_HOME point to that one

Answer (score 0):

[`openjdk-11-jdk-headless_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04_amd64.deb`](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jdk-headless_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2%7E20.04_amd64.deb) and [`openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04_amd64.deb`](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2%7E20.04_amd64.deb) package shows (by extracting with 7-zip) that OpenJDK 11 will be installed at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`.

This will give you enough information about appending environment variables such as `PATH` and `JAVA_PATH`.

And, there may be a path called `default-jvm` or so, you may use that path accordingly.